# Is there a faster way to implement this looping function?

Tags: python, loops

Is there any way I can make this function faster?? I am trying to create the 3 x 3 alpha_j matrix defined by:

[image]

I have,

```
def a_j(r, a, A):
    alph = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],complex)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            alph[i,j] = (r * a * A[i,j])
    return alph
```

Comment: Can you describe your question in a way that doesn't use the word "this", but instead makes the title descriptive enough to distinguish the question from others (and let someone else know if they have the same problem) from the title alone?

Comment: You didn't write what are `r` and `a`, but what happens if you just do `alph = r * a * A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without any loop:

```
def a_j(r, a, A):
    alph = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],complex)
    alph= (r * a * A)
    return alph
r = 5
a = 10
A = np.array([[2,6,1],[0,4,9],[1,8,3]],complex)
ans  = a_j(r,a,A)
print(ans)
```

Output of this code:

```
[[ 100.+0.j  300.+0.j   50.+0.j]                                                                                    
 [   0.+0.j  200.+0.j  450.+0.j]                                                                                    
 [  50.+0.j  400.+0.j  150.+0.j]]
```

Output of your code:

```
[[ 100.+0.j  300.+0.j   50.+0.j]                                                                                    
 [   0.+0.j  200.+0.j  450.+0.j]                                                                                    
 [  50.+0.j  400.+0.j  150.+0.j]]
```

Notice outputs are same means you can do it without any for loop

Answer (score 0):

You could use list of comprehension, like this:

```
def a_j(r, a, A):
    return np.array([[np.complex(r * a * A[i,j]) for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)])
```